# Is CSS sprite also useful for mobile websites?

Tags: css, xhtml, windows-mobile, mobile-safari, mobile-website

Is CSS sprite also useful for mobile websites? Would it be good to combine all possible images to combine. but all are not being used on same page? Mobile browsers has limited cache space.

Answer (score 3):

Very much so, if your target browsers support it. Contemporary browsers (Android, IPhone, WP7) certainly do. Sprite images are typically not huge, and reducing requests is a big win on mobile networks.

Answer (score 2):

To go one step further than Craig Stuntz answer, only load what you need. Separate your sprites out into groups (eg, Images that load on all pages, Images that load on page X, images that load on page Y, etc.)

The smaller the footprint the better.

Comment: @OldCode101 - Hmm..I was thinking in a same way.